# Minimum of $\tan x+\tan y+\tan z$ using Lagrange multipliers for acute angled triangle $\Delta xyz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

Consider an acute angled triangle $\Delta xyz$. Suppose we want to minimise the function $f(x,y,z)=\tan x+\tan y+\tan z$. So as per the method of Lagrange multipliers here is what I did.

> $$\begin{aligned}&\text{minimise}: f(x,y,z)=\tan x +\tan y+\tan z \\ &\text{given: }x+y+z=\pi \end{aligned}$$

---

$$\begin{aligned}\sec^2 x&=\lambda\\ \sec^2 y&=\lambda \\ \sec^2 z&=\lambda\end{aligned}$$

Now we have the constraint $x+y+z=\pi$ and $0\lt x,y,z\lt \pi/2$. Also do have $4$ unknowns and $4$ equations to solve for $x,y,z,\lambda$. But I am not clear on how to use these equations, managing the $\pm$ signs when we take square roots. Besides if it was not given that $\Delta xyz$ is acute angled, then the minimum would have been in the case of a degenerate triangle when any one of the angles is $0$ and others add up to $\pi$, in which case, $f(x,\pi-x,0)=0$, but I do not understand the jump from $0$ to $3\sqrt{3}$ either for the minimum. Can it not attain values in $(0,3\sqrt{3})$? Why? . Any hints are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you are fine with with not using langranges multiplier jensen inequality on $f=\tan x$ gives result directly

Comment: But it is an acute angled triangle so $x, y, z \lt \frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\tan$ will be positive. So you get $x = y = z = \frac{\pi}{3}$.

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore I am studying Lagrange multiplier, so that is why I specifically ask for methods to proceed from this step. Inequality methods are known to me.

Comment: Look at the definition of $\sec$. What's the sign for an acute angle?

Comment: @Andrei What about the jump from minimum in the degenerate case being $0$ and for the feasible set being $3\sqrt{3}$?Why is there a jump when we move from the boundary into the feasible set?

Comment: @ParasKhosla Consider an acute triangle $ABC$. How do you make it degenerate? You move one point, say $A$ towards $BC$. At some point, the triangle becomes obtuse. At that point the secant becomes negative, as well as the tangent. So there is a discontinuity in the solution space when one angle is $\pi/2$

Comment: Also note that $0$ is not a minimum. If one of the angles is just slightly obtuse, the tangent of that angle approaches $-\infty$.

Comment: @Andrei Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You are welcome. Just for fun, assume $x=y$, and then plot $2\tan x+\tan(\pi-2x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To handle this problem with the Lagrange Multipliers method, we need first of all, convert the inequalities into equations so with the help of slack variables $(s_x,s_y,s_z,e_x,e_y,e_z)$ the formulation could be

$$
\min_{x,y,z} \tan x + \tan y + \tan z\ \ \  \text{s. t.}\cases{x+y+z=\pi\\
x = s_x^2\\
y = s_y^2\\
z = s_z^2\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-x = e_x^2\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-y = e_y^2\\
\frac{\pi}{2}-x = e_z^2\\
}
$$

and the corresponding lagrangian

$$
L = \tan x + \tan y + \tan z + \lambda(x+y+z-\pi)+\sum_{k=\{x,y,z\}} \eta_k(k-s_k^2)+ \sum_{k=\{x,y,z\}} \mu_k\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-k-e_k^2\right)
$$

so the set of stationary points for $L$ could contain the solution. Now the minimization problem has the variables $\{x,y,z,\lambda,\eta_k,\mu_k,s_k,e_k\},\ \ k=\{x,y,z\}$. Also, to avoid algebraic problems to obtain the solutions for equations involving trigonometric functions, we can use

$$
\tan x\approx x + \frac{x^3}{3}
$$